# Finding the average amount of iterations for choosing a unique set out of a group of numbers with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, means, bernoulli-numbers

We need to pick a set of unique numbers (**with replacement**!) out of a collection of  `n`  unique numbers. Each number has the same probability to be picked. Each iteration we pick randomly one number from this collection. We end once we have a set of unique numbers where the amount of numbers in the set is exactly 10% of the original collection (amount of numbers in the set is `n/10`). What would be the mean of the **amount of** **iterations** we have to preform in order to get to this request?
Because we are allowed to keep choosing random numbers from the collection we are certain that eventually we will have a unique set, where the minimum amount of iterations are of course n/10, but what would be the mean amount of iterations??

I was trying to use Bernoulli method but quickly found out it is not covering the right answer.
Is there something I am missing out? What would be the proper approach?
Thanks for the Help

Comment:  changed as asked

Comment: Anything else is unclear @ThomasAndrews ?

Comment: This is a variant of the well known [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: Ultimately, this will be an inclusion-exclusion question.